# how to get Springs ApplicationContext in Struts2?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, struts2, classpath

I have a struts2 Web project with Spring plugin. The applicationContext.xml is sitting at

```
/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
```

How would I acces it inside my class

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: You should configure your container (i.e. Tomcat) to load the application context during its startup.

Comment: any specific use-case to load the context this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really going about this the correct way as you shouldn't be loading the application context. However, have you tried:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
```

I would suggest that you add the following to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This will ensure that the Spring IOC container is initialised when your application starts. You can then use Spring to provide your actions with the necessary dependencies wired in. You shouldn't need to get hold of the IOC container as you are doing since this is not dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Only files under `WEB-INF/classes` would come under classpath. You should better move it to `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

You can also load the context file from your web.xml using one of Spring context listeners.
Can you explain why you are loading Spring config into your webapp? That would give us a better idea to suggest.